# tkinter update() and update_idletasks()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I 'm reading a lot of `update()` and  `update_idletasks()`.
I did a GUI with some widgets. One button is called Run and it runs a motor endless. Another button is called Stop, and as you can image, it is to stop the movement of the motor. All works properly but the `print("update")` is called more and more often. At the first cycle of the motor 2 time, cycle by cycle leak source from the OS.
How can I solve the issue? I tried with `update_idletasks()` as well. instead to `self.update()` i could insert a function just to read the Stop button. any idea?

```
class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.globalvar()
        self.bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
        self.master = master
        #----------Load the GUI
        self.loadGUI()
        self.up()
    def Running(self):
        while self.s:
           movethemotor()
           self.up()
    def Stop(self):
        
        self.s = False
        print("Stop")
    
def up(self):
        ...
        self.master.update()
        self.master.after(100,self.up)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("MLCT GUI")
    rpi = GUI(root)
    root.geometry('1050x530')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Another things that get me cracy: if I replace the "up" function:

```
def up(self):
        ...
        root.update()
        root.after(100,self.up)
```

I can read the print update, one time the first cycle, 2 time the second, 3 times the third etc.

Comment: Is `Running()` called?  If yes, then you should not call `after()` inside `up()`.

Comment: Yes Running() is called from the Button "Run". Why shouldn't ? it means from my understanding "after 100ms (more or less) call the function self.up".

Comment: But `up()` is called repeatedly inside `Running()`.  So there will be more and more `after()` are scheduled.

Comment: Yes, I inserted this loop. It sholld be like
        def up(self):
        ...
        self.master.update()
        time.sleep(0.1)
       self.up()
I need it to update the GUI when nothing happen: if none click any button the GUI refresh itselve. This because I display also measures from sensors, encoders and time. So they also need to be read in a while loop wating for a button event.

Comment: Then you should create another function for `after()` and call `up()` inside this function.